# How to avoid error while type-checking in packages which has no tsconfig in lerna monorepo?

Tags: typescript, monorepo

I have a lerna monorepo with two different types of packages: js and css.

I need to type check on only those packages which have `tsconfig.json`.

When I try to run `lerna exec tsc`, it fails with error on those packages which do not have `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the shell:

```
lerna exec '! [ -f tsconfig.json ] || tsc'
```

(Someone else feel free to add the Windows equivalent...)

Comment: I'm sorry but lerna doesnt recognize neither ```!``` nor ```-f``` (
It throws error

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

- in every package with tsconfig add `"type-check": "tsc"` into
  packages's package.json
- in monorepo's package.json add script `"type-check": "lerna run
  type-check"`